# How to send coordinates from node.js server to leaflet.js client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, leaflet

I am trying to send a coordinate from node.js and socket.io server (`index.js`) to `client.html`. In HTML client the coordinate will be read by Leaflet. The problem is, the coordinate variable cannot be read or NaN in client.html

I have tried a simple direct variable initiation and follow the tutorial in Socket.IO pages

**Server (index.js)**

```
var e = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(e);
var sio = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000);

e.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/client.html');
});

sio.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('ping', function(msg) {
    socket.emit('pong',  {lat:parseFloat(35+Math.random()),lon:parseFloat(-106+Math.random())});
    });
});
```

**Client (client.html)**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('pong', function(msg) {
        console.log("Nilai msg : "+msg);
        L.marker([parseFloat(msg.lat),parseFloat(msg.lon)]).addTo(map).bindPopup("("+msg.lat+","+msg.lon+")").openPopup();



var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [35.10418, -106.62987],
    zoom: 9
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

map.on("click", function(){
socket.emit('ping', {msg: 'Hello'});

});
```

I expect the map will show the marker with the corresponding coordinate, but the actual output is `Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)`

Answer (score 4):

In socket.io, [`ping`](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98ping%E2%80%99) and [`pong`](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98pong%E2%80%99) are reserved events and [shouldn't be used in your app](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2414). What your browser receives on a `pong` event is not what you expect:

> ms (Number) number of ms elapsed since ping packet (i.e.: latency).

and that's why `msg.lat` and `msg.lon` are not defined and cannot be parsed.

Change the event names to something else, say `fromserver`  and `frombrowser` and you should be good to go :

Server side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('frombrowser', function(msg){
        var o = {lat:parseFloat(35+Math.random()),lon:parseFloat(-106+Math.random())};
        socket.emit('fromserver', o);
    });
});
```

Client side:

```
socket.on('fromserver', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    console.log([parseFloat(msg.lat), parseFloat(msg.lon)]);
});

map.on("click", function(){
    socket.emit('frombrowser', {msg: 'Hello'});
});
```